# Friends blocks not showing up

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend and I are playing Minecraft PE on two different devices both on the newest version of Minecraft and whenever he places a block its always the same. For example if he tries to place a diamond block it shows up as cobblestone.

Answer (score 1):

That happens to me to whenever I play with my brother. The block or the object you want to put down has to be on the first GUI to get it working. I had the same trouble.